# How to center my ASCII ART containing text in <pre>

Tags: html, ascii, center, pre

I've recently made a website that I coded the old-fashioned way (ASCII art on it).

My problem is that I've got complex ASCII drawing on the code that contains text insertion in the drawing itself, and that the all thing is centered. First i added a `<center>` before the `<pre>` and calculated the different spaces to make a perfectly symmetrical centered drawing. It worked perfectly well on my browser but it makes bad adjustments in others browsers, moving the different lines. 
So I've added a :

```
div.fixedwidth {

  width: 1800px ;

}
```

before the `<pre>` block as a way for the drawing to conserve its centering without altering it. It works for me but not for everyone depending on the dimensions of their screen or the browser they use.
I give you the website : http://midnight.website/
It is the building drawing that is going crazy...

The other thing is that I've got a text into the structure of my ASCII drawing. I think I made a bad choice by giving it a specific font size like this : `<font size="3">`, forgetting that this kind of insertion in an ASCII drawing is a highly risked choice regarding the different calculations different browsers or screen size have.

So my questions are :

- Is there a way to center my `pre` ascii drawing and to be sure it will not be deformed in others screens and to be fixed in the page even if we resize it ? (Actually my website is perfectly calibrated on my browser, the building is well aligned)
- Is there a way to make different sizes for the text inside the ascii drawing as a way not to deform the drawing that contains it ?

The code is too long for a good transcript, but you can check the source code on my website.

Thank you for your help !

Comment: Why not use a centered responsive div with dynamic font size?

Comment: Yes i'd love to but how do i make this ?

Answer (score 1):

Slick website

1. Yes, there is. As far as I know though your art needs to have a fixed character width; so you'll have to add some white space. Afterwards you can just apply text-align:center; to your `<pre>` tag.
2. I found a really neat trick where you could set the character width proportional to the view-port. with the 'font-size: 1vw;'

`pre {text-align:center;font-size: 1vw;}`

I'm also working on a website with ascii art. So I found this question while I was struggling with the same thing.

I found the second part of my answer here:
https://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/

Finally. Here's the JSfiddle I made to demo it.
https://jsfiddle.net/rtesbrok/6/